# 'str' object has no attribute 'open' in python

Tags: python, streamlit

I have created a simple streamlit app which has two option one is file upload another one is capturing image
while trying to open the uploaded file i am getting an error 'str' object has no attribute 'open' .
I am not sure why the issue is occurring kindly let me know how to solve this so that i can move forward

```
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
import cv2
from  PIL import Image


Image = st.sidebar.selectbox(
     'Choose your method',
     ('Upload','Capture'))

if Image == 'Upload':
    uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("HI",type=['jpg','png','jpeg'])
    if uploaded_file is not None:
        image = Image.open(uploaded_file)
        st.image(image,width=300) 
else:
    file_image = st.camera_input(label = "Take a pic of you to be sketched out")
```

Comment: `Image = st.sidebar.selectbox(...)` You are overwriting the imported `PIL.Image` class. Use another name for that variable

Answer (score 1):

You have here two `Image` keywords, one of them is the `Image` library you imported from PIL, and the other is the return from your selectbox, which is a string.

Since the second one is declared later, it has overridden the first one, thus giving you this error when you try to call `open`.

I suggest renaming the second one to anything else and it should work properly.

Comment: Opps my bad.....Thanks for the correction